# typescript generic constraint keyof T and string: ts2322

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Im trying to write a generic class that keeps a pair of special pointers to a generic type's keys. Here is a [playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBA%20gSwCYGkCmBPGBeGBlDAWwCMQAbACgHJFVMqBKAKFEljghACcp0tcCJctQ7de9ZkzQAPAA5iYCMFDRcAZgENgaGACENENHijc0AYXBqEAcwA8AFQA0Me8hgyVYJBBgBrTCBqLs72EL7u0p7efgFB9jAAPjAArl5oVmBoSAB8MADeTDCKdBgA-ABcLsiFMJw8fBUuYUwAvkxScgrAZAY%20%20obGpg4hbh5oXj7%20GIEuMABktVBcStYhYRFRk7GzSalI6UpZuQVFssnEZAjAMADatHwAupVTM-FJVMhUNWcXV7ei9UwD0aLziiRSaQyWXaRVY0C4yWAJi4FBORWKfBwMA%20SCojhqRTq4gw%20KKLUq-SMyPMlhswyqSDWvmyDHyBJgUAAFggIHdkI8sfzMOyuTy7kSBbgJcKya0gA) of this MVP

```
const _idKey = Symbol('_idKey')
const _sortKey = Symbol('_sortKey')

export interface BaseStoreConfig<T, Tid extends keyof T, Tsk extends keyof T | undefined> {
  idKey?: Tid
  sortKey?: Tsk
}

export class BaseStore<T, Tid extends keyof T & string, Tsk extends keyof T | undefined> {
  public [_idKey]: keyof T | 'id'
  public [_sortKey]?: keyof T | undefined

  constructor({
    idKey = 'id', // Errors, see below
    sortKey,
  }: BaseStoreConfig<T, Tid, Tsk>) {
    this[_idKey] = idKey
    this[_sortKey] = sortKey
  }
}
```

This produces a ts2322 Error (I've tried several variations of the `Tid` constraints, I always come back to this error)

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Tid'.
  'string' is assignable to the constraint of type 'Tid', but 'Tid' 
   could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'string'.ts(2322)
```

I generally understand this error, but in this instance I'm confused. How can a subtype of `string` not be assignable to  this type? is there any way to express this constraint?

Comment: Consider `const z: 'foo' & string = 'id';` - this won't work because 'id' is not assignable to 'foo', so you have the same problem here if you pass in some T with keys other than 'id'. 

As for "is there any way to express this constraint?" - not 100% sure on what you're trying to do here. I think your design point of using 'id' as a default key, without making assumptions on the shape of T will lead to confusing typing. Perhaps you could add some examples of usage, what should work, what shouldn't etc and I could help further

Comment: I don't totally understand that. `Tid` needs to be a keyof `T`, so `T` can't be `'foo'` or there would be no possible type for `Tid`. Isn't using `keyof` forcing `T` to be an object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that Typescript doesn't really support different types for the same value (e.g., `idKey`) based on whether the value is being viewed from the caller's side (`Tid` or `undefined`) or from the implementer's side (`Tid` or `"id"`).  There are similar issues like [microsoft/TypeScript#42053](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42053) filed as bugs, but I'm not sure when they'll be addressed.

You've annotated the constructor parameter as being of type `BaseStoreConfig<T, Tid, Tsk>`, whose `idKey` property is of type `Tid | undefined`.  In trying to assign a default value of `"id"` to it, the compiler sees that as a mismatch... because `"id"` may not be assignable to `Tid`.  The particular error mentioning `string` instead of  specifically `"id"` seems to be some change to TypeScript since after 3.9 (not sure why but I'm assuming it does reasonable things elsewhere).  If you revert to 3.9 [and look at it](https://tsplay.dev/RwRYvW) you'll see the error mentioning `"id"` explicitly.

---

So I think the fix here is to not do default values inside the destructuring, because there's no great way to represent the two-different-types-for-the-same-value thing.  Instead let's just move the default value to the body of the constructor:

```
  constructor({
    idKey, sortKey,
  }: BaseStoreConfig<T, Tid, Tsk>) {
    this[_idKey] = idKey ?? "id" // okay
    this[_sortKey] = sortKey
  }
```

Now everything compiles with no errors.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.5#code/MYewdgzgLgBA+gSwCYGkCmBPGBeGBlDAWwCMQAbACgHJFVMqBKAKFEljghACcp0tcCJctQ7de9ZkzQAPAA5iYCMFDRcAZgENgaGACENENHijc0AYXBqEAcwA8AFQA0Me8hgyVYJBBgBrTCBqLs72EL7u0p7efgFB9jAAPjAArl5oVmBoSAB8MADeTDCKdBgA-ABcLsiFMJw8fBUuYUwAvkxScgrAZAY++obGpg4hbh5oXj7+GIEuMABktVBcStYhYRFRk7GzSalI6UpZuQVFssnEZAjAMADatHwAupVTM-FJVMhUNWcXV7ei9UwD0aLziiRSaQyWXaRVY0C4yWAJi4FBORWKfGcdXEGEcNRalX6RmR5ksNmGVSQa182QY+RqRSgAAsEBA7shHjgMZgYKVSjAAETIAUMmDM1l3bGc3BSzD41rtIA)